# How to update rpm/yum database?

Tags: fedora

For example I have installed mysql and httpd, but when I'm trying to 'yum update' then yum throws error that package is available but not installed.
So, how can I update database of installed software?

This command have no effect:

```
rpm --rebuilddb
```

Comment: do this for me. "rpm -qf /usr/sbin/httpd" and please paste the actual error, as well as the output of that command in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got a system with files from packages installed but an out-of-sync RPM database, you can use `rpm -ivh --justdb somepackage.rpm` to update the RPM database without actually installing anything. This is pretty messy, though, and really when you're in this state, it's time to start planning a reinstallation from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot update the rpmdb manually; it must be done via packages.

Comment: So I must to reinstall all the packages?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams - Do you mean to say that rpmdb checksums cannot be updated directly?

Answer (score 0):

How did you install httpd and mysql? It sounds like you did it through source, in which case you won't be able to update it using the repository.

Comment: MySQL and httpd are installed using yum, but some time ago I backuped binaries and config (without --archive option) and unzipped into new installed system (yum and yum configs to). So how can I do update without new installation? Or how can I reupdate rpm database?

Comment: Try `yum clean all; mv /var/lib/rpm/__db* /root/; rpm –rebuilddb; yum update`. If not, you may have to backup the binaries again, install it using yum, then restore from your backups.

Comment: Not works, maybe there some another ways to synchronize software?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
yum clean all
yum search mysql
```

Make sure your repos are loaded that have the mysql package you want

Comment: It worked earlier successfully, I just need to update RPM database, see the next answer comment - it will describe my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's definitely a language barrier issue here -- the rest of this post is going to assume you installed MySQL and Apache through yum, not from source, and then yum update broke on you.

Check (and post) the rest of your yum output. If a package is available but cannot be installed, that usually means that one of its dependencies is faulty, which happens often if you have both the i386 and x86_64 versions of a package installed and you somehow end up with different versions. Once you get your dependency chain cleaned up, yum update should work normally.